# SQL - how to efficiently select distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sqlperformance

I've got a very performance sensitive SQL Server DB. I need to make an efficient select on the following problem:

I've got a simple table with 4 fields:

```
ID [int, PK]
UserID [int, FK]
Active [bit]
GroupID [int, FK]
```

Each UserID can appear several times with a GroupID (and in several groupIDs) with Active='false' but only once with Active='true'.

Such as:

```
(id,userid,active,groupid)
1,2,false,10
2,2,false,10
3,2,false,10
4,2,true,10
```

I need to select all the distinct users from the table in a certain group, where it should hold the last active state of the user. If the user has an active state - it shouldn't return an inactive state of the user, if it has been such at some point in time.

The naive solution would be a double select - one to select all the active users and then one to select all the inactive users which don't appear in the first select statement (because each user could have had an inactive state at some point in time). But this would run the first select (with the active users) twice - which is very unwanted.

Is there any smart way to make only one select to get the needed query? Ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "last" and "point in time" imply some date field, but I don't see one.

Comment: or are the ids monotonically increasing?

Comment: exactly! the IDs are autoincremented.

Comment: You show a denormalized data set where groupid appears to depend on userid.  Is that an accurate representation of your data, or can groupid vary across the records for a single userid?

Comment: @Larry - GroupID does not depend on a UserID. Those are independent. Each use could appear on several groups and each group can contain several records of the same user (with other fields which are not relevant for the question). The data is normalized.

Answer (score 0):

What about a view such as this :

```
createview ACTIVE as select * from USERS where Active = TRUE
```

Then just one select from that view will be sufficient :

```
select user from ACTIVE where ID ....
```

Comment: That's not so good - because there are hundred thousands of records in that table - I wouldn't like to get all of the active ones...

Comment: Indeed, the CREATE VIEW will take a few moments to be done, but that runs only once !

Comment: Unless you're creating a materialized view, the view does *not* run until you read data from it, and then it runs every time you read data from it.

Comment: Indeed, thnks for the precision.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select
   ug.GroupId,
   ug.UserId,
   max(ug.Active) LastState
from
   UserGroup ug
group by
   ug.GroupId,
   ug.UserId
```

If the active field is set to 1 for a user / group combination you will get the 1, if not you will get a 0 for the last state.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea.... :) Though it seems that the MAX function couldn't be used on a bit field

Comment: But if the `true` record is not the "most recent", you'll still get `true` even though the user is no longer active in that group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of the use of an "isActive" column the way you're doing it.  This requires two `UPDATE`s to change an active status and has the effect of storing the information about the active status several times in the different records.

Instead, I would remove the `active` field and do one of the following two things:

1. If you already have a table somewhere in which `(userid, groupid)` is (or could be) a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX` then add the `active` column to that table.  When a user becomes active or inactive with respect to a particular group, update only that single record with `true` or `false`.
2. If such a table does not already exist then create one with '(userid, groupid)`as the`PRIMARY KEY`and the field`active` and then treat the table as above.

In either case, you only need to query this table (without aggregation) to determine the users' status with respect to the particular group.  Equally importantly, you only store the `true` or `false` value one time and only need to `UPDATE` a single value to change the status.  Finally, this tables acts as the place in which you can store *other* information specific to that user's membership in that group that applies only once per membership, not once per change-in-status.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tbl t 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) id
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY userid 
) m
ON t.id = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand what you want your query to return but anyway. This query will give you the users in a group that is active in the last entry. It uses [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) so you need at least SQL Server 2005.

Table definition:

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  UserID int,
  Active bit,
  GroupID int
)
```

Index to support the query:

```
create index IX_YourTable_GroupID on YourTable(GroupID) include(UserID, Active)
```

Sample data:

```
insert into YourTable values
(1, 0, 10),
(1, 0, 10),
(1, 0, 10),
(1, 1, 10),
(2, 0, 10),
(2, 1, 10),
(2, 0, 10),
(3, 1, 10)
```

Query:

```
declare @GroupID int = 10

;with C as 
(
  select UserID,
         Active,
         row_number() over(partition by UserID order by ID desc) as rn
  from YourTable as T
  where T.GroupID = @GroupID
)
select UserID
from C
where rn = 1 and
      Active = 1
```

Result:

```
UserID
-----------
1
3
```